# Sequelize many-to-many relation with custom foreign key

Tags: many-to-many, sequelize.js

I'm making a model of the existing database. My table has many-to-many self-reference through a junction table. Junction table has two fields: 'parent_id' and 'child_id'.
I am trying to define the association like that:

```
    company.hasMany(company, {as: 'parents', foreignKey: 'child_id', through: 'company_relation'});
    company.hasMany(company, {as: 'children', foreignKey: 'parent_id',  through: 'company_relation'});
```

But when I'm trying to set child companies, Sequelize is still looking for 'children_id' foreign key in junction table, not for 'child_id', as I defined:

```
    company.setChildren([child]);
```

returns an error:

```
error: column company_relation.children_id does not exist
```

How can I define custom foreign key in junction table, if I don't want to name my associations in singular, like that:

```
    company.hasMany(company, {as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'child_id', through: 'company_relation'});
    company.hasMany(company, {as: 'child', foreignKey: 'parent_id',  through: 'company_relation'});
```

Is there any other way? Thank you, and sorry if it's hard to understand me :)

Answer (score 2):

Read this [doc](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Associations) about association

I debug instance all time then i have problem with this, he have [custom name method (set[As])](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Associations#hasmanytarget-options) for association children (if use option "as"):

```
for(var method in company) {
 console.log(method);
}
```

i refused from "option.as" because you need all time write it instead dao model

Answer (score 0):

Even though you define the foreign key in sequelize association, you may forget to define the references in your schema.

You can check the code from the [document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#check-associations)
Title : Enforcing a foreign key reference without constraints.

And in your situation, the define schema for you company is like below:

```
child_id:{
    references: {
        model: 'Company',
        key: 'id'
    }
},
parent_id:{
    references: {
        model: 'Company',
        key: 'id'
    }
},
```

Hope this would help you